# Фильтрация символов

Tags: php, строки, unicode

Как можно фильтровать текст от различных невидимых символов а также кодов на подобие `58#̏̏f57#͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏58#̏̏f57#͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏58#̏̏f57#͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓͓̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏58#̏̏` (Заранее извиняюсь)  и других не приятных вещей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Определите диапазон символов юникода, которые считаете допустимыми.
2. С помощью регулярного выражения замените все символы вне этого диапазона на `""`.

Comment: Возможно есть какие нибудь готовые "диапазоны" ? так как перебрать все символы unicode и найти нужные символы сложно, так как их очень много. или есть какие то другие решения для получения нужного диапазона?

Comment: @RedWoolf все диакритические знаки находятся в одном блоке.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $text=filter_var($text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)
```

Можно и так удалить невидимые символы и спец символы, пример смотрите сдесь http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc0c40676c96d65bc737e392c4960b146f9edf1d

Comment: Хотелось бы сохранить, большинство нормальных символов  таких как ☺, © и других